# Creating a program that reads counts the number of lines in a C++ file

Tags: c++, file, fstream

im looking to count the number of lines in a code i have figured that i need to look for a specific character from the file and increment by one each time that it is found. Now i have a general gist of it but im having trouble figuring out how to read each line in the file. I have posted what i have so far. Any help would be appreciated

```
#include<fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 int main()
{
   ifstream readfile;
   readfile.open("project1b.cbp");
   int number_of_lines=0;
   char = ch;
   while(ch !=EOF)
   {
       if(ch!='endl'||';')
        number_of_lines++;
   }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(std::getline(string, file)) n_lines++;` -- btw, why is this tagged C?

Comment: Is this part of an exercise? If not I would suggest taking a look at http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::getline` for getting each line.

Comment: They need "lines of code" though.

Comment: You can do a simple check for line[0] and line[1] for the characters you are expecting in single line comments.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
   if(ch!='endl'||';')
```

does NOT do what you think. You are checking that `ch` is not equal to `endl`, or that `;` is. And since `;` is always true (not zero), you are not really having a very useful comparison here.

You might be thinking of

```
   if(ch!='endl'|| ch!=';')
```

Or something like that. Not sure what you are trying to achieve with your comparison...

As for the other part of your question - the top Google hit for "C++ read file line by line" gets you to the following stackoverflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/1967396

It's all you need.

One more thing - you need to define more clearly for yourself what a "line of code" is. Is basically "any carriage return, or any semicolon" a new line? What about semicolon followed by new line? What about a line with two semicolons (two statements on one line)?

It will take a bit more puzzling on your part to clear up your thinking. I recommend that you split the logic into

1. Get a line from the file
2. Count semicolons
3. If there are semicolons, is there anything else of note after them
4. Decide how to count these

Final thought: the single quote `' '` is used to define a character constant. The double quote `" "` is used to define a string constant.  The end of line character is usually `\n` or `\r`; in C++ we use `std::endl` as a way to write that - but it's not in quotes. And when you use `namespace std` presumably you can just write `endl` when you mean `'\n'`. But putting single quotes around it confuses me - and probably the compiler too.

Comment: ah i see. what i am trying to get is that if i have either one of these chars in my line that it counts as a line and to increment the number of lines counter by one.

Comment: @user3006893 and what do you expect `'endl'` to be? Did you even read any documentation? It's a random multi-character string literal, it's not something you get when you reach the end of a line (you get `'\n'` or `'\r'` when you do).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  if(argc!=2){
    cout<<"Syntax: "<<argv[0]<<" <FILENAME>"<<endl;
    return -1;
  }

  ifstream readfile(argv[1]);
  if(!readfile.good()){
    cout<<"Failed to open file: '"<<argv[1]<<"'!"<<endl;
    return -1;
  }

  int number_of_lines=0;
  while(readfile.good()){
    char ch=readfile.get();
    if(ch=='\n'|| ch==';')
      number_of_lines++;
  }

  cout<<"Number of lines: "<<number_of_lines<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Some differences from your code.

- I use [argc and argv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean) so that the user can specific a file name on the command line.
- I load the file with `ifstream readfile(argv[1])`. This fits the [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (Resource Acquistion is Initialization) scheme commonly used in C++. I don't use a `close()` statement because the ifstream will go out of scope and automatically clean itself up. Using RAII makes your code cleaner and less-prone to errors.
- I use [`get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) to acquire new characters from the character stream. This was missing in your code.
- The end of the line occurs when the `\n` (newline) character is the one we're currently looking at, or if we are looking at the `;` character. [`endl`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/) is not a character constant - it's more of a stream manipulator - so you cannot use it in the manner you do, nor to do comparisons of this sort in general.
- Note that the or operator (`||`) divides two complete logic statements, the way in which you use it (`(ch!='endl'||';')`) does not work the way you think it does.
- I opt to use [K&R style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) bracing rather than your heathen [Allman/GNU style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#GNU_style). (This is something of a joke, but I encourage you to try several different styles and find one that's right for you. I prefer K&R for SO because the code is more compact.

You should ask yourself if this is really the way you want to count lines of code. For instance, a for construct (`for(int i=0;i<N;++i)`) will end up looking like three lines of code using your metric.

Comment: thank you for your help. the program you provided gave me a push into the right direction. I do not really know of the K&R style as I am I student we are a basically left in a sense to our own devices. But I kind of picked up the style you mentioned due to the fact that it  feels most logical to me. I can see all of my braces with out have to worry about missing one. I think this was something that i developed on my own. I do have a question on if you had any tips on becoming a better programmer like yourself. I sometimes feel as if my school has failed me. Or is this a common for the noobs?

Comment: I feel as if my programs that I make they work but they are very short. That could just be a testament to my style of thinking and thinking of making everything as simple as possible?

Comment: Developing an aesthetic sense of how your code should look is useful: indentations and brackets. I like the K&R style because I rarely forget brackets and therefore want them to be unobtrusive. When I started, I wanted to learn how to program games. Figure out how to code a "Guess the Number" game, try to code [Hunt the Wumpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_the_Wumpus). Always start with a simple version of the game then add elements to make it more complicated.